# enhance project with linq framework

Tags: c#, winforms, linq-to-sql

Hi can anyone advice where can i search for a good linq to sql framework sample?
Preferably if it includes CRUD and validation. I have done many projects in linq to sql. But everytime when i want to start a new project using linq to sql, i have a hard time to start all over again. It is time to get some framework.

Comment: Your question is really too wide, but here is at good starting point for you: [Using LINQ to SQL (Part 1)](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/05/19/using-linq-to-sql-part-1.aspx) by Scott Guthrie.

Answer (score 0):

Read the following tutorials:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386976.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb425822.aspx

http://www.sidarok.com/web/blog/content/2008/05/02/10-tips-to-improve-your-linq-to-sql-application-performance.html